# How to optimize this script performing INSERTS into a database?

Tags: mysql, perl

So i already complete a script that will insert data into mysql table and move those file into a directory until all files are none. There around 51 files and it took around 9 sec to complete the execution. So my question is . is there a better way to speed up the execution process?

the codes are

```
our $DIR="/home/aimanhalim/LOG";
our $FILENAME_REGEX = "server_performance_";
# mariaDB config hash
our %db_config = ( "username"=>"root", "password"=> "", "db"=>"Top_Data", "ip" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => "3306");
main();

exit;


sub main()
{
    my $start = time();
   print "Searching file $FILENAME_REGEX in $DIR...\n";
   opendir (my $dr , $DIR) or die "<ERROR> Cannot open dir: $DIR \n";
   while( my $file = readdir $dr )
   {
      print "file in $DIR: [$file]\n";
      next if (($file eq ".") || ($file eq "..") || ($file eq "DONE"));   



      #Opening The File in the directory
      open(my $file_hndlr, "<$DIR/$file");

      #Making Variables.
      my $line_count = 0;
      my %data = ();
      my $dataRef = \%data;
      my $move = "$DIR/$file";
      print "$file\n";
      while (<$file_hndlr>) 
      { 
         my $line = $_;  
         chomp($line);
         print "line[$line_count] - [$line]\n";
         if($line_count == 0)
         {
            # get load average from line 0
            ($dataRef) = get_load_average($line,$dataRef);

            print Dumper($dataRef);

         }
         elsif ($line_count == 2)
         {

          ($dataRef) = get_Cpu($line,$dataRef);
          print Dumper($dataRef);

         }

$line_count++;
      }

      #insert db
      my ($result) = insert_record($dataRef,\%db_config,$file);
      my $Done_File="/home/aimanhalim/LOG/DONE";


sub insert_record(){

 my($data,$db_config,$file)=@_;
 my $result = -1; # -1 fail;  0 - succ

  # connect to db
  # connect to MySQL database
  my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=".$db_config->{'db'}.";host=".$db_config->{'ip'}.";port=".$db_config->{'port'};
my $username = $db_config->{'username'};
my $password = $db_config->{'password'};

my %attr = (PrintError=>0,RaiseError=>1 );
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$username,$password,\%attr) or die $DBI::errstr;

print "We Have Successfully Connected To The Database \n";

  $stmt->execute(@param_bind);
  ****this line is insert data statement***
  $stmt->finish();
    print "The Data Has Been Inserted Successfully\n";
  $result = 0;
  return($result);

  # commit
  $dbh->commit();
  # return succ / if fail rollback and return fail
  $dbh->disconnect();

}
exit;
```

editted

so pretty much this is my code with some sniping here and there.

i tried to put the 'insert_record' below the comment #insert db but i dont think that do anything :U

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Comment: @ssr1012 sorry my bad  i edit back the post

Comment: @Сухой27 if so how ?

Comment: In fact you're doing it the _slowest_ way possible, opening a new database connection for every single row you insert. You might like my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are connecting to the database for every file that you want to insert (if I read your code correctly, there seems to be a closing curly brace missing, it won't actually compile). Opening new database connections is (comparably) slow.

Open the connection once, before inserting the first file and re-use it for subsequent inserts into the database. Close the connection after your last file was inserted into the database. This should give you a noticable speed up.

(Depending on the amount of data, 9 seconds might actually not be too bad; but since there is no information on that, it's hard to say).

Comment: is it wierd to not have disconnect and commit in the script ? because when i have those thing it gives me an error of segemntation fault (core dump) but when i remove it ... it works fine

Comment: You should still be able to handle multiple transactions within a single connection. Depending on your requirements, it might be enough to commit only once after all the datae has been inserted

Comment: but the problem is that even without the commit and disconnect  statement it works fine

Comment: Once your program terminates, any open resource (such as database connections, file handles) will be closed automatically. I assume without any errors, any open transaction will auto-commit.

Comment: @MiteMiteKyle It might also be, that the connection automatically creates a single transaction which can only be committed once. Consecutive `commit` probably create errors (or segfaults? Seems but bit weird, but well) If you want multiple transaction, you would have to create them manually (reusing the existing connection).

Comment: If you do not set AutoCommit to 0 (false), it is set to true by default. Hence, your insterts are commited automatically. That is why your code works without $dbh->commit();

Comment: Another slight way to optimize is to put all insertions into a single `INSERT` statement, but that probably isn't worth it.